# PHP Functions from included files don't execute on Web Server

Tags: php, function, include, webserver, hosting

I am in the process of migrating a site from my personal dev server onto Windstream's business hosting server.  I've already run into the issue of having developed using PHP 5.4 only to find out that my static functions won't work on WS's 5.1.4 installation.  I've since fixed those issues and am not facing one that I can't seem to find any help for on the internet.

All of the static functions I was using have been rewritten as functions outside the class scope.  Instead of having

```
class Product{
...
public static function myFunction(){}
...
}
```

I now have

```
function myFunction(){}

class Product{...}
```

in my included Product.php file.

However, when I try to call `myFunction()` from my code, nothing happens.  I know the nothingness comes from WS's error handling, but the point is, the function isn't working.  To verify this, I have taken the following steps:

Inserted the line `echo "entered included";` immediately following the `<?php` in Product.php.  This prints "entered included" on the index page, indicating that my `include` is working.  I have done the same thing before the final `?>` with the same results, so I don't think it's getting hung up inside the included file.

I have changed myFunction() in the included file to be simply

```
function myFunction(){echo "myFunction works";}
```

A call to `myFunction()` still makes nothing happen.

I have moved myFunction() to the including file (myFunction() now lives in index.php instead of Product.php; index includes Product.php).  This time, myFunction() executes without issue.

To my 'hack it til it does what it should' sensibilities, this tells me that the server is having a problem with functions that are declared in files that are included; honestly, though, I have absolutely no clue what's going on, and any help would be appreciated.  Their website is currently down, and they were expecting it to only be offline for a day, so I'll try pretty much anything short of sacrificing a fatted calf.

I know I should be posting more specific code, but since this is a customer's actual website, I'm trying to put as little of the actual code out here as is possible.  I'm happy to append specific sections of code to this entry as they are requested for clarification.

Thanks in advance for your consideration.

@Rottingham:  First, thanks for the 3v4l link.  Second, my assumption about static methods in 5.4 vs 5.1.4 came from this line of php.net's page on static members and methods:

"As of PHP 5.3.0, it's possible to reference the class using a variable. The variable's value can not be a keyword (e.g. self, parent and static)."
src - http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php

Since my version and the server version were on different sides of the 5.3 mark mentioned, I incorrectly assumed that this was my problem.

Third, when I get in from my day job, I'll update my code to show errors and update this post if a solution has not yet been found.

Ultimately, my problem isn't with using static methods (since I don't have them anymore) but with using any function that is declared in an included .php file.

Comment: Why can't you use Product::myFunction() static functions in PHP 5.1.4?? You really need to turn on error reporting so you can get a clearer picture, or look at the error.log file in your websites directory. You could put at the head of your index.php file `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to get some information out of PHP

Comment: PS static functions work just fine in PHP 5.1.4 - just a reference so you don't waste time making global methods when its not necessary. http://3v4l.org/Errvh